# Java - Properties file "config"

Tags: java

I'm still learning programming, and currently I have a java project loading in config.properties through the code below.

```
public static void run(File dir) throws IOException, URISyntaxException, Exception {
    File configFile = new File(dir + File.separator + fileName);

    if (!configFile.exists()) {
        System.out.println("[JenkinsBot] Config file created, please edit it!");            
        FileGenerator.ExportResource(dir, fileName);
        Main.death = true;
    } else {
        Parameters params = new Parameters();
        FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<FileBasedConfiguration> builder = new FileBasedConfigurationBuilder<FileBasedConfiguration>(PropertiesConfiguration.class).configure(params.properties().setFileName("resources/config.properties"));
        Configuration cfg = builder.getConfiguration();

        if (cfg != null) {
            System.out.println("[JenkinsBot] Config file loaded!");             
            Main.discordToken = cfg.getProperty("Token").toString().replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "").replaceAll("^\'|\'$", "");                
        } else {
            System.out.println("ERROR: " + fileName + " is null, at this point it should not be. Please check your files.");
        }
    }       
}
```

From this I am able to obtain a string called "Token", which looks like this in the config file.

```
# Discord token - This is required for your bot to connect. Please follow the following instructions to setup a bot.
# https://github.com/jon-skocik/Jenkins-Bot/wiki/Creating-a-discord-bot-&-getting-a-token
Token: exampletokengoeshere
```

I'm attempting to pull what I *thought* was a "String List", but am unable to figure this out.

```
feeds:
  - www.google.com
  - www.youtube.com
  - www.reddit.com
```

My end goal is for users to add onto that list, and for me to be able to iterate through them and throw them into a hashmap. Any help or direction would be great. I was playing with `cfg.getProperties("feeds").keySet()` but that wasn't doing what I wanted it to.

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: a) "That wasn't doing what I wanted it to" is very vague. b) You want people to be able to dynamically add values to a properties file? Why?

Answer (score 0):

Your feeds block looks like [YAML](http://yaml.org) to me. If so there are Java parsers out there, liked from the YAML page.